# Is there an equivalent of word2vec for images?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm wondering if it would be possible to create dense vector representations for an image, similar to how you might create a word embedding with an algorithm like Word2Vec?

I understand that there are some big differences between text and image data – specifically the fact that word2vec uses the word's context to train – but I'm hoping to find a similar counterpart for images.

If a simplistic example of w2v ([from Allison Parrish's GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/aparrish/2f562e3737544cf29aaf1af30362f469)) is:

```
            | cuteness (0-100) | size (0-100) |
|–––––––––––|––––––––––––––––––|––––––––––––––|
| kitten    |        95        |     15       |
| tarantula |         8        |      3       |
| panda     |        75        |     40       |
| mosquito  |         1        |      1       |
| elephant  |        65        |     90       |
```

And another example being `king - man + woman = queen`

Is there some analog (or way of creating some type of analog) for images where you might get something generally along these lines (with some made-up numbers):

```
                             | amount of people | abstract-ness |
                             | in image (0-100) |    (0-100)    |
|––––––––––––––––––––––––––––|––––––––––––––––––|–––––––––––––––|
| Starry Night               |         0        |       75      |
| Mona Lisa                  |         1        |        9      |
| American Gothic            |         2        |        7      |
| Garden of Earthly Delights |        80        |       50      |
| Les Demoiselles d'Avignon  |         5        |       87      |
```

(and just to clarify, know the actual vectors created by an algorithm like Word2Vec wouldn't cleanly fit into human-interpretable categories, but I just wanted to give an analogy to the Word2Vec example.)

or `(starry night) - (landscape) + (man) = (van Gogh self portrait)` or `= (abstract self portrait)` or something generally along those lines.

Those might not be the best examples but just to recap, I'm looking for some sort of algorithm for creating an abstract n-dimensional learned representation for an image that can be grouped or compared with vectors representing other images.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely! But...

Such models tend to need significantly *larger* and *deeper* neural-networks to learn the representations.

Word2vec uses a very-shallow network, and performs a simple prediction of neighboring-words, often from a tightly limited vocabulary, as the training-goal which (as a beneficial side-effect) throws off compact vectors for each word.

Image-centric algorithms instead try to solve labeling/classification tasks, or regenerate original images under compressed-representation (or adversarial-classifier) constraints. They use 'convolutions' or other multi-layer constructs to intepret the much-larger space of possible pixel values, and some of the interim neural-network layers can be interpretable as compact vectors for the input images.

Note that even in textual word2vec, the individual "dense embedding" dimensions, learned in an unsupervised fashion, **don't** have neat human-interpretability (like "bigness", "cuteness", etc.). Often, certain directions/neighborhood of the high-dimensional space are vaguely-interpretable, but they're not precise nor aligned exactly with major dimension axes.

Similarly, any compact representations from deep-neural-network image-modeling won't inherently have individual dimensions with clear meanings (unless specific extra constraints with those goals were designed-in) – but again, certain directions/neighborhoods of the high-dimensional space tend to be meaningful ("crowds", "a car", "smiles", etc).

A nice overview of some key papers in deep-learning based image-analysis – the kinds of algorithms which throw off compact & meaningful vector summaries of images – that I just found is at:

https://adeshpande3.github.io/The-9-Deep-Learning-Papers-You-Need-To-Know-About.html